# Firestore document doesn't exist when apple reviewing my app

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore document doesn't exist when apple review my app. I dont know why.
Here is my firestore database:

[image: Firebase database]

Firebase rulers:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{documents=**} {
        allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

I try to run on Simulator and my device (use Testflight), everything work fine. But when I submited to appstore, apple reviewer said my app crash when running. Here is crash log from Fabric:

`Document '<FSTDocumentKey: public/configs>' doesn't exist. Check document.exists to make sure the document exists before calling document.data.`

[image: Document '<FSTDocumentKey: public/configs>' doesn't exist. Check document.exists to make sure the document exists before calling document.data.]

I know I can fixed this by check `.exist` property. But I want to know what I'm wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, I knew what wrong here.
After installed app, reviewer turn off the internet connection.

`For Android and iOS, offline persistence is enabled by default.`

In the first time, reviewer opening app, firestore will query from offline data, which doesn't exist in this time.

Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline?authuser=0